# AttributeError at /accounts/regist_save/ 'User' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

AttributeError at /accounts/regist_save/ 'User' object has no attribute 'user'　error happens.I wrote in views.py
I wrote in views.py

```
def regist(request):
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form, 
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)

@require_POST
def regist_save(request):

    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and regist_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                regist = regist_form.save(commit=False)
                regist.is_staff = True
                regist.save()

                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = regist.user

    return render(request, 'registration/detail.html')
```

in regist.html

```
<div class="form-group-lg">

    <label for="id_username">Username</label>

    {{ regist_form.username }}

  </div>

  <div class="form-group-lg">

    <label for="id_email">Email</label>

    {{ regist_form.email }}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group-lg">

    <label for="id_password">Password</label>

    {{ regist_form.password1 }}

  </div>


  <div class="form-group-lg">
    <label for="id_password">Password2</label>

    {{ regist_form.password2 }}
    <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p>

  </div>



  {% load static %}

  <div class="form-group-lg">
    <label for="sex">SEX</label>
    <select id="sex" class="form-control sex" name="sex">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="male">male</option>
      <option value="female">female</option>
    </select>
  </div>


  <script src="{% static 'accounts/register.js' %}"></script>


      <button type="submit" class="btn-lg regist">REGIST</button>

      <input name="next" type="hidden" />

  {% csrf_token %}

</form>
```

in models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class NewUser(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        birthday = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, default=None)
        sex = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens because I think `profile.user = regist.user` can be gotten the user.I tried to write `profile.user = request.user` but IntegrityError happens.How can I get the user?Why can't i get it by using this code?Am I wrong to write User model 's column name?What should i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `regist` itself is user object.

just try:

```
profile.user = regist
```